# How to calculate average of variables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, range, average

I am trying to calculate date ranges between rows and then get an average.

```
declare @date0 date = (
  select top 1 my_date 
  from someTable 
  order by my_date desc)
declare @date1 date = (
  select my_date 
  from someTable 
  order by my_date desc
  offset 1 rows 
  fetch next 1 row only)
declare @date2 date = (
  select my_date 
  from someTable 
  order by my_date desc
  offset 2 rows 
  fetch next 1 row only)
declare @date3 date = (
  select my_date 
  from someTable 
  order by my_date desc
  offset 3 rows 
  fetch next 1 row only)

select 
[Range 1]   = dateDiff(day, @date1, @date0),
[Range 2]   = dateDiff(day, @date2, @date1),
[Range 3]   = dateDiff(day, @date3, @date2),
[Avg Range] = avg(
                nullIf(@date0, 0), 
                nullIf(@date1, 0), 
                nullIf(@date2, 0), 
                nullIf(@date3, 0)
              )
```

The range calculations work fine, but a bit clumsy.

However, I'm not sure how to handle the average. It looks like the function is supposed to run against a table and not an array, but I was having issues inserting the variables into a temp table column.

How can I get the average of these ranges (not including `range = 0`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION ALL to return a row for each case:

```
select avg(t.[Range]) [Avg Range]
from (
  select dateDiff(day, @date1, @date0) [Range]
  union all
  select dateDiff(day, @date2, @date1)
  union all
  select dateDiff(day, @date3, @date2)
) t
where t.[Range] <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`AVG` is an aggregate function, designed to be used with `GROUP BY` or windows. You can simply do the math in your query:

```
select 
[Range 1]   = dateDiff(day, @date1, @date0),
[Range 2]   = dateDiff(day, @date2, @date1),
[Range 3]   = dateDiff(day, @date3, @date2),
[Avg Range] = (
               nullIf(@date0, 0) +
               nullIf(@date1, 0) + 
               nullIf(@date2, 0) + 
               nullIf(@date3, 0)
              ) /
              (
               CASE WHEN @date0 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
               CASE WHEN @date1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
               CASE WHEN @date2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
               CASE WHEN @date3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
              )
```

Comment: Good idea, but the `/4` pattern is not dynamic so will break where a date range is `null`.

Comment: @Matthew so you want to divide by 3 if one date is null?

Comment: @Matthew see my edit; that will only take the average of the non-null values.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to use four different queries:

```
with dates as (
    select
        row_number() over (order by my_date desc) rn,
        datediff(days, lag(my_date) over (order by my_date desc), my_date) diff
    from T
)
select avg(nullif(diff, 0)) from dates where rn <= 3;
```

or

```
with dates as (
    select
        datediff(days, lag(my_date) over (order by my_date desc), my_date) diff
    from T
    order by my_date desc
    fetch next three rows only
)
select avg(nullif(diff, 0)) from dates;
```

Using `distinct` would also let you easily get the top three dates and not have to mess around with `nullif()`.

```
with dates as (
    select distinct
        datediff(days, lag(my_date) over (order by my_date desc), my_date) diff
    from T
    order by my_date desc
    fetch next three rows only
)
select avg(diff) from dates;
```